# Applying replacement function for NULL elements in nested lists

Tags: r

I am scraping json from an apartment rental platform's rest api.

Let's say I have the following data structure, which conveys the square footage of each rental unit in a single building:

```
sqft1 <- list(c("1500"),
              NULL,
              c("1300"))
```

It's important that I retain the dimensionality of this data. If I try to unlist and aggregate into a data frame alongside other rental unit properties, I will lose the 2nd element and get thrown an error.

But by finding the indices in the list that have a NULL element, I can replace them with a character vector containing an empty string as follows:

```
isNull1 <- lapply(1:length(sqft1), function(x) is.null(sqft1[[x]]))
sqft1[unlist(isNull1)] <- c("")
```

My problem arises when I try to apply the same replacement function over a result set for multiple buildings. After running the following block, no replacements get made.

```
sqft3 <- list(list(c("1500"),
                   NULL,
                   c("1300")),
              list(c("1400"),
                   c("1700")),
              list(NULL,
                   c("1200")))
isNull3 <- lapply(1:length(sqft3), function(x) lapply(1:length(sqft3[[x]]), function(y) is.null(sqft3[[x]][[y]])))
lapply(1:length(sqft3), function(x) sqft3[[x]][unlist(isNull3[[x]])] <- c(""))
```

What concept about applying functions am I misunderstanding here? Any ideas how to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested `lapply` as follows

```
lapply(sqft3, function (x) lapply(x, function (y) ifelse(is.null(y), "", y)))
```

This is similiar to @MKR's solution.

---

Using the `purrr` package, you could also use `modify_depth`

```
library(purrr)
modify_depth(sqft3, .depth = 2, .f =  ~ifelse(is.null(.x), "", .x))
```

---

The `ifelse` from above could also be replaced by this function `%||%` ("null-default", also from `purrr`) as follows

```
modify_depth(sqft3, 2, `%||%`, "")
```

(`%||%` is short-hand for `if (is.null(x)) y else x`)

Result

```
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] "1500"
# 
#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] ""
#
#[[1]][[3]]
#[1] "1300"
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] "1400"
#
#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] "1700"
#
#
#[[3]]
#[[3]][[1]]
#[1] ""
#
#[[3]][[2]]
#[1] "1200"
```

Comment: Nested lapply: awesome. Thanks for the variety of solutions!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `map` function twice as:

```
map(sqft3,function(x){
  map(x, function(y){
    y[is.null(y)] <- ""
    y
  })})


# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] "1500"
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] ""
# 
# [[1]][[3]]
# [1] "1300"
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "1400"
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] "1700"
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]][[1]]
# [1] ""
# 
# [[3]][[2]]
# [1] "1200"
```

**Data:**

```
sqft3 <- list(list(c("1500"),
          NULL,
          c("1300")),
     list(c("1400"),
          c("1700")),
     list(NULL,
          c("1200")))

sqft3 
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] "1500"
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# NULL
# 
# [[1]][[3]]
# [1] "1300"
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "1400"
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] "1700"
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]][[1]]
# NULL
# 
# [[3]][[2]]
# [1] "1200"
```